# How do I parse a JSON response from Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to parse a `response.text` that I get when I make a `request` using the Python Requests library. For example:

```
def check_user(self):
    method = 'POST'
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/login'
    ck = cookielib.CookieJar()
    self.response = requests.request(method,url,data='username=test1&passwd=pass1', cookies=ck)
    print self.response.text
```

When I execute this method, the output is:

```json
{"request":"POST /login","result":"success"}
```

I would like to check whether `"result"` equals `"success"`, ignoring whatever comes before.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [manual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) suggests:  `if self.response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:`

If that doesn't work:

```
if json.loads(self.response.text)['result'] == 'success':
   whatever()
```

Answer (score 11):

Since the output, `response`, appears to be a dictionary, you should be able to do

```
result = self.response.json().get('result')
print(result)
```

and have it print

```
'success'
```

Comment: `response` is a 'Response' object that has no attribute 'get'. I've tried to parse "manually" `response.text` as a string and works fine, but I think it is not a good way to do it

Comment: ok, I have just seen right now the update; it works fine this way

Answer (score 4):

If the response is in json you could do something like (python3):

```
import json
import requests as reqs

# Make the HTTP request.
response = reqs.get('http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/group_list')

# Use the json module to load CKAN's response into a dictionary.
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)

for i in response_dict:
    print("key: ", i, "val: ", response_dict[i])
```

---

To see everything in the response you can use `.__dict__`:

```
print(response.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    import json

    def check_user(self):
        method = 'POST'
        url = 'http://localhost:5000/login'
        ck = cookielib.CookieJar()
        response = requests.request(method,url,data='username=test1&passwd=pass1', cookies=ck)

        #this line converts the response to a python dict which can then be parsed easily
        response_native = json.loads(response.text)

        return self.response_native.get('result') == 'success'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. It is not necessary to use `json` module. You can create a `dict` using `dict = eval(whatever)` and return, in example, `dict["result"]`. I think it is more elegant. However, the other solutions also work and are correct

Comment: `eval()`'ing a random (untrusted) api response seems like a terrible idea security-wise.

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns Which are the threats in this case? I am asking because I ignore them

Comment: @horo Eval will evaluate the response as valid Python. By using it, you're trusting the source not to inject malware in the response.

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns how could you solve this security issue then? I mean, is there like a security-wise way to perform an evaluation of the response?

Answer (score 0):

Put in the return of your method like this:

`return self.response.json()`

If you wanna looking for more details, click this following link:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp

and search for json() method.

Here is an code example:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/python/demopage.js'
x = requests.get(url)
print(x.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, maybe the response would be as **expected**. So It'd be great if we can built a mechanism to catch and log the exception.

```py
import requests
import sys

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106702/how-do-i-parse-a-json-response-from-python-requests"
response = requests.get(url)

try:
    json_data = response.json()
except ValueError as exc:
    print(f"Exception: {exc}")

    # to find out why you have got this exception, you can see the response content and header
    print(str(response.content))
    print(str(response.headers))
    print(sys.exc_info())

else:
    if json_data.get('result') == "success":
        # do whatever you want
        pass
```