# How to import to json an API url in Python

Tags: python, json, import

I have to work with a dataset from an API. I am trying to import the data in json format but I got errors.

This is my code:

```
import requests as rq
r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint')
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.text[:1000])
```

And this is the result:

> 200
>   application/json; charset=utf-8
>       [{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":"BikePoints_1","url":"/Place/BikePoints_1","commonName":"River Street , Clerkenwell","placeType":"BikePoint","additionalProperties":[{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","category":"Description","key":"TerminalName","sourceSystemKey":"BikePoints","value":"001023","modified":"2019-08-19T14:23:57.613Z"},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","category":"Description","key":"Installed","sourceSystemKey":"BikePoints","value":"true","modified":"2019-08-19T14:23:57.613Z"},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","category":"Description","key":"Locked","sourceSystemKey":"BikePoints","value":"false","modified":"2019-08-19T14:23:57.613Z"},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","category":"Description"

I want to import this to a json and then transform the data into a dataframe.

Could anyone show me the correct way?

Comment: The response is ok but I need to transform this data to a dataframe and this is when I can't find the way

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what errors you get.

Comment: what have you tried already? what libs did you use?
here is a simple tutorial on how to serialize/deserialize json into python objects:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-json-data-in-python/

Comment: #this line converts the response to a python dict which can then be parsed easily
import json
response_native = json.loads(r.text)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106702/how-do-i-parse-a-json-response-from-python-requests

Comment: @VijayAgrawal I use what you said: response_native = json.loads(r.text) and got this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text .. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: r.json() is a better option - did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `read_json()` function in `pandas` to get it. Here is how you can retrieve data from the api.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint')
r = r.text
df = pd.read_json(r)
print(df.head())
```

```
                                               $type            id  ...        lat       lon
0  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...  BikePoints_1  ...  51.529163 -0.109970
1  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...  BikePoints_2  ...  51.499606 -0.197574
2  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...  BikePoints_3  ...  51.521283 -0.084605
3  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...  BikePoints_4  ...  51.530059 -0.120973
4  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...  BikePoints_5  ...  51.493130 -0.156876
```

Comment: Thanks @Axois, from what you showed me I need to take some values and make graphs. Could you please tell me if there is any way to see the results sorted in rows an columns?

Comment: If you would like to print out a specific column of data, you can just simply call `df.lat` for example, which will return an array which you can manipulate.

Comment: Thank you @Axois, and is it possible to extract this df to a CSV file?

Comment: @Alexa You bet there is. You can save it to a csv file using `df.to_csv('output/filename.csv')`

Comment: Thank you @ Axois. I have one question more. Usually I work with data in dataframe, where every value has own cell.. is it posible to show the info in that format?

Comment: And how can I access to the first column? It has a $ and when I try df.$type it sends me an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: @Alexa `df["$type"]`